# Какое время глагола?

Tags: глаголы, времена

*Встало весеннее солнышко.*

Скажите, тут прошедшее время глагола или можно и в настоящем времени так сказать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Солнышко что сделало? — встало. Это прошедшее время, совершенный вид.